# FFMPEG: H265, Maxrate Not Working

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This command works for me with the h264 codec.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c:v libx264 -maxrate 800k -bufsize 800k -ar 48k -ab 192k b.mp4
```

However, with libx265 instead of libx264 in that command, the output ends up exactly the same as it be would be without the maxrate and bufsize parameters in it. It's as if h265 ignores those parameters. Is that the case, or is there another reason why this might not be working?

UPDATE:

I changed libx265 to hevc_nvenc. Now, it seems to process maxrate and bufsize correctly, but not b:v. In contrast, libx265 can process b:v but not the aforementioned maxrate and bufsize!

UPDATE 2: FFmpeg's x265 wrapper has been updated and it's now finally able to pick up libavcodec's bufsize and maxrate.

Comment: What's the output bitrate obtained?

Comment: @Gyan

1) With libx265: -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k outputs
2458 kbps
2648 kbps.

2) With hevc_nvenc: -b:v 2000k outputs
2380 kbps
2569 kbps

Comment: ok, let me check ffmpeg's x265 wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg's x265 wrapper does not pick up libavcodec's bufsize and maxrate, so for now, you can pass it privately.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c:v libx265 -x265-params "vbv-maxrate=800:vbv-bufsize=800" ...
```

Units are in kilobits, unlike libavcodec, which are in bits.

I'll update this post once the wrapper picks up the generic options.

Comment: Why does it work with hevc_nvenc but not with libx265? Are there any cons for me to just stick to hevc_nvenc? Oh cool, will the wrapper get the generic options in the near future?
Btw, thanks for all the help and info!

Comment: Hopefully, I'll get to push it within a couple of days.

Comment: Looks like it's been pushed now. Awesome!

Comment: Applied yesterday.